# Upload Opencv-Contrib in Serverless Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, aws-lambda, serverless

Whenever I tried to upload opencv-contrib-python library to AWS through Serverless Framework, seems that the requeriments file is not taking into account the contrib library

Include the libraries in the requirements.txt file

```
    opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16
    opencv-python==3.4.2.16
```

Whenever a features descriptor is being called

```
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

An error in the code appears as is the library was never included

```
    AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to include only the '**contrib**' library and remove the original one. At the end the **requirements.txt** file must contain only the following lines:

```
    numpy==1.16.1
    opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17
```